# Symfony and DoctrineBehavior/translatable with two default locales?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation, symfony6

I'm looking for an elegant way to have the following behavior in Symfony 6.

I use [DoctrineBehaviors/translatable](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/docs/translatable.md) to store some fields in several languages, let's say 'en', 'fr' and 'de'.

The users have a small dropdown on my navbar, with which they can choose the locale in which they read the site. Changing the locale in this dropdown, triggers a redirection to the routes in the format given below, to display the entities in the chosen locale:

```
/{_locale}/entity/{id}
```

Now the tricky part: I would like to have two default locales, 'en' and 'fr', as fallbacks for a reader whose 'de' translation is missing.

Let's say my entities have the following translations (`--` means translation is **ABSENT from database**, not empty string):

```
A : [ en fr de ]
B : [ en -- -- ]
C : [ -- fr -- ]
D : [ en fr -- ]
```

I would like the following routes to display text like this:

```
/en/entity/A --> en
/fr/entity/A --> fr
/de/entity/A --> de

/en/entity/B --> en
/fr/entity/B --> en
/de/entity/B --> en

/en/entity/C --> fr
/fr/entity/C --> fr
/de/entity/C --> fr

/en/entity/D --> en
/fr/entity/D --> fr
/de/entity/D --> (not important as long as either en or fr is displayed)
```

Today, as I can have only one `default_locale`, I must choose either 'fr' or 'en', but if I choose 'en', then /de/entity/C will display an empty 'en' translation, and if I choose 'fr', then /de/entity/B will display an empty 'fr' translation.

I've tried to setup two fallbacks in translations.yaml but it doesn't work, I fear it's more used by translations in translation files, and not in database.

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
    translator:
        fallbacks: ['fr', 'en']
```

Thanks in advance if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Well I answer my own question, to give the solution I found, in case it interrests anyone future.

In order to achieve what was wanted, I abandonned DoctrineBehaviors/translatable and replaced it with [DoctrineExtensions/translatable](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/translatable.md). What I found convenient with it is the database storage:

- The translated labels go to a table distinct from the table representing your entity
- The label column in the entity table is set in the first place with whichever translation provided when entity is created. After that, it remains until anyone provides the translation in the default locale: at that moment, the label in the entity table is replaced by it.

Let's see some examples, based on my question above:

- Default locale is `en`
- Other locales are `fr` and `de`

### Example 1: creation in the default locale

Sequence of events:

1. User creates an entity with locale `en`

```
Database storage:
   Entity table: en label
   Translations table: empty
```

So far, everyone sees the entity with `en` label.

2. User translates the entity with locale `fr`

```
Database storage:
   Entity table: en label
   Translations table: fr label
```

After that, people set to `en` see `en` version, people set to `fr` see `fr` version.

### Example 2: creation NOT in the default locale

Sequence of events:

1. User creates an entity with locale `fr`

```
Database storage:
   Entity table: fr label
   Translations table: fr label
```

So far, everyone sees the entity with `fr` label.

2. User translates the entity with locale `de`

```
Database storage:
   Entity table: fr label
   Translations table: fr and de labels
```

So far, people set to `en` see `fr` version, people set to `fr` see `fr` version, people set to `de` see `de` version.

3. User translates the entity with locale `en`

```
Database storage:
   Entity table: en label
   Translations table: fr and de labels
```

After that, people set to `en` see `en` version, people set to `fr` see `fr` version, people set to `de` see `de` version.

That's exactly what I wanted to have. Enjoy, folks!